# Google sheet - how to filter the data with custom date range

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I know this can be achieved with pivot in google sheet but it wont let us to select the date range to fetch the results in pivot. What i need is when I select the date range and agent in sheet 2 it returns me the result with total uploaded qty.

My Data Set in Sheet 1

[image]

Result Required in Sheet 2

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rw7gA4dVBjlR82uOGO4aW6AwtN7LTd_wgkTHk-B7mw8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={QUERY(Data!A:D, 
 "where A = '"&C2&"' 
    and B >= date '"&TEXT(A2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and B <= date '"&TEXT(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 1); "","", "Total", 
 IFNA(SUM(QUERY(Data!A:D, 
 "select D 
  where A = '"&C2&"' 
    and B >= date '"&TEXT(A2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and B <= date '"&TEXT(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)), "")}
```

[image: 0]